# How to get incremental data from Apache cassandra?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cql

I want to get incremental data, that is each call to select query should returns new records. For ex. let's say my table has 1 million records and I am using Spring boot application so I don't want to fetch all the records at once. I want the records recursively like in the chunks of 10k records or any number.

Once I get the records let's say 10k, in the next iteration I need other 10k and so on.

How can I do it in Apache Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

You want Pagination in Cassandra, Cassandra has the SELECT with LIMIT but not the built-in "SKIP" functionality.

Is not easy to implement it, but try this approach see the example:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html#reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__paging-through-unordered-results

The other option you need to implement in client/driver side.
https://shivanshugoyal0111.medium.com/pagination-in-cassandra-b7e45ec2656a